# Merge 2 Arrays and Sum the Values (Numeric Keys)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have 2 arrays

```
Array
(
    [010156] =&gt; Array
    (
        [supp_number] =&gt; 010156
        [totalamount] =&gt;     4.113,23
        [debtorcred] =&gt; H
        [amount1] =&gt;     4.113,23-
        [amount2] =&gt;

        [amount3] =&gt;
        [amount4] =&gt;
        [amount5] =&gt;
        [amount6] =&gt;
    )
)



Array
(
    [010156] =&gt; Array
    (
        [supp_number] =&gt; 010156
        [totalamount] =&gt;     4.113,23
        [debtorcred] =&gt; H
        [amount1] =&gt;     4.113,23-
        [amount2] =&gt;

        [amount3] =&gt;
        [amount4] =&gt;
        [amount5] =&gt;
        [amount6] =&gt;
    )
)
```

Is it possible that I can combine these separate arrays into one and add the values together so that the outcome will be:

```
Array
(
    [010156] =&gt; Array
    (
        [supp_number] =&gt;  <<<TOTAL >>>
        [totalamount] =&gt;     <<<TOTAL >>>
        [debtorcred] =&gt; <<<TOTAL >>>
        [amount1] =&gt;      <<<TOTAL >>>
        [amount2] =&gt;  <<<TOTAL >>>

        [amount3] =&gt;  <<<TOTAL >>>
        [amount4] =&gt;  <<<TOTAL >>>
        [amount5] =&gt;  <<<TOTAL >>>
        [amount6] =&gt;  <<<TOTAL >>>
    )
)
```

This is the function I have at the moment but I cannot seem to make it work:

```
function array_merge_numeric_values()
{
  $arrays = func_get_args();
  $merged = array();
  foreach ($arrays as $array)
  {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
      if ( ! isset($merged[$key]))
      {
        $merged[$key] = $value;
      }
      else
      {
        $merged[$key] += $value;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: FYI, you seem to have a missing closing brace in the last code block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This actual calculation can be done in 2 lines of code, no need for loops:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/ieSkHQ

```
$arr1 = array('amount1' => 1, 'amount2' => 6);
$arr2 = array('amount1' => 2, 'amount2' => 7);
$add = function($a, $b) { return $a + $b; };
$summedArray = array_map($add, $arr1, $arr2);
print_r($summedArray);
```

Youl'll just need to make the appropriate adjustment to account for you nested structure.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new empty array and loop in the first array as following:

```
$array1 = array('my_num' => 10, 'my_num2' => 20);
$array2 = array('my_num' => 15, 'my_num2' => 25);
$newArray = array();
foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
    if(isset($array2[$key])){
        $newArray[$key] = $value+$array2[$key];
    } else {
        $newArray[$key] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$value` in your case is an array, not a value. You can try this:

```
function array_merge_numeric_values()
{
    $arrays = func_get_args();

    $merged = array();
    foreach ($arrays as $array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value)
        {
            if(!isset($merged[$key]))
            {
                $merged[$key] = array();
            }

            foreach($value as $kk => $vv)
            {
                if ( ! isset($merged[$key][$kk]))
                {
                    $merged[$key][$kk] = $vv;
                }
                else
                {
                    $merged[$key][$kk] += $vv;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```