# How to Add two array values in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merge 2 Arrays and Sum the Values (Numeric Keys)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105707/merge-2-arrays-and-sum-the-values-numeric-keys)

I have two arrays both have same keys, i want to add key values,

Example

```
$arr1 = array("first"=>10,"second"=>20);
$arr2 = array("first"=>20,"second"=>30);

want to create new array which add these two array values 

like

$arr3 = array("first"=>30,"second"=>50);
```

How can i do that in one line, i can do it using forach or other technique, but wondering if some one know a good way of doing?

Comment: Why do you have to do do it in one line? Is this an homework?

Comment: I mean if there is a function which do combining like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example for string keys (note that no error checking is done!):

```
$arr1 = array("first"=>10,"second"=>20);
$arr2 = array("first"=>20,"second"=>30);

$arr3 = $arr1;
array_walk($arr3, function (&$val, $key, $foo) { $val += $foo[$key]; }, $arr2);

print_r($arr3);

/*Array
(
    [first] => 30
    [second] => 50
)*/
```

Comment: I'm rusty in my PHP but what's `$foo`?

Comment: `$foo` is just a variable (for which I didn't come up with a better name). The way `array_walk` works, it will hold `$arr2`'s values.

Comment: Ahh, ok, I think I get it know, I really need to read up on PHP again. I was trying to do this one liner trying to combine `array_map` and `array_merge` but haven't figured out yet. Good answerbtw +1