# multiply 2 arrays with eachother in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I currently have the 2 arrays below:

Array 1:

```
$rekeningnummer = $_POST['input']; // example "9876543219"
$rekeningnum_array = str_split($rekeningnummer);
```

Array 2:

```
$gewichten = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
```

How do I multiply a $rekeningnum_array object with the array object of $gewichten?

So as a example: 9+1, 8+2, 7+3 etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750966/how-to-add-two-array-values-in-php just go trough this

Comment: @AmitGaud I do not work with values and keys this time.