# Summing arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sum

Imagine the following two arrays:

```
$array1 = array('dogs' => 3, 'cats' => 5);
$array2 = array('dogs' => 2, 'cats' => 7);
```

Is there a native php 5.5 function, or any optimal solution to get the following result?

```
$result = array('dogs' => 5, 'cats' => 12);
```

Comment: `$array1['dogs'] + $array2['dogs']`

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes. But you have to write a custom function for that. Jonah, gave a good answer for that.

[Here is a solution for numeric arrays.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105707/merge-2-arrays-and-sum-the-values-numeric-keys)

For associative arrays:

```
$sum = array_combine(array_keys($array1), array_map('bcadd', $array1, $array2));
```

(`bcadd` lets you avoid creating your own addition function)

Comment: i used the reference, and also forwarding to the actual link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be best to write your own solution for multidimensional sums:

```
<?php

function sumEach($original, $array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(!array_key_exists($key, $original))
            $original[$key] = $value;
        else
            $original[$key] += $value;
    }
    return $original;
}

$totals = array();

$totals = sumEach($totals, $array1);
$totals = sumEach($totals, $array2);

?>
```

Then your output from `$totals` will look like:

```
Array(
    'dogs' => 5,
    'cats' => 12
);
```

Here's a demo: https://eval.in/73948